# Android: Facebook login error

Tags: android, logcat, facebook-login, android-simple-facebook

I am using this library: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook, I have setup a login button and there are no errors in the code, when I launch the app and click on the button i get this error in LogCat:

`com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: UnknownError: ApiException:Key hash 7ZIgCYiW5AevLOlv3kPROmyZ0-w does not match any stored key hashes.`

How can i fix this? I have tried changing the key hash in the facebook settings, but i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this! Apparently facebook messes up with the - and + symbols, so i changed it to / instead, and then it worked!